# Matrix with N columns and N rows , columns must have N-1 , N-2 etc value

Tags: c++, debugging, matrix

I'm having trouble with a matrix . The requirements are:

Make a matrix with `N` columns and `N` rows, the first column must have the value `N` , the second column must have `N-1`, the third `N-2` etc until the last column must have value 1.

For example: `N[7][7]` must be:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

My code only gets : `7 6 6 6 6 6 6` for each row and column. How can I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m[24][24], i, j, k = 0;
    int linia, coloana, piesa, lac=0;
    int mutari = 0;
    int ceva;
    cout << "Cate linii si cate coloane ? :";
    cin >> lac;
    ceva = lac;

    if (lac>1 && lac<25) {
        for (i = 0; i < lac; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < lac; j++)
            {

                m[i][0] = lac;
                m[i][1] = ceva-1;
                ceva = ceva;

                m[i][j] = ceva - 1;
                ceva = ceva;

                if (i == j) {
                    m[i][j] = 2;
                    m[1][1] = 2;
                }
            };              
        };

        for (i = 0; i < lac; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < lac; j++)
            {
                cout << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    else cout << "Numarul de linii si coloane trebuie sa fie >=2 si <= 24" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I encourage you to learn how to use a debugger. With a good debugger, you will be able to step through your code line by line and inspect the values of the variables in order to spot where your logic fails

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: for all i,j `m[i][j]` must equals to `lac-j`, isn't it ?

Comment: Your example has columns and rows inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should neatly initalize the matrix.

```
if (lac>1 && lac<25) {
    for (i = 0; i < lac; i++)
    {
        ceva = lac;
        for (j = 0; j < lac; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = ceva;
            ceva = ceva-1;
        }
    } // no need for ';' here

    for (i = 0; i < lac; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < lac; j++)
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

At the beginning of each row, we use `ceva = lac;` to reset the value that will go into the matrix.
Immediately after setting the value, we decrease `ceva` by one.
I stripped out a lot of code whose purpose I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

After Tim Randall showed you how to fix your code, this is the C++ way of doing things:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Rows: ";
    std::size_t rows;
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "Columns: ";
    std::size_t cols;
    std::cin >> cols;

    std::size_t elements{ rows * cols };
    std::vector<int> m(elements);
    std::generate(m.begin(), m.end(), [&]() { return --elements % cols + 1; });

    for (std::size_t y{}; y < rows; ++y, std::cout.put('\n'))
        std::copy(m.begin() + y * cols, m.begin() + (y + 1) * cols,
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    // access m[y][x] with m[y * cols + x]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier on yourself and leverage the power of the standard library.

```
constexpr auto N = 7;
std::array<int, N> row{};
std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> matrix{};

std::iota(std::rbegin(row), std::rend(row), 1);
std::fill(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), row);
```

`std::array` is just a very thin wrapper around c-style arrays, is slightly nicer to work with, and has nice features such as remembering its size.
`std::iota` fills a range with sequentially increasing values (in this case starting at `1`). By using `std::rbegin`, we tell it to fill our `row` in reverse.
Finally we use `std::fill` to set each row of our `matrix` to `row`.

The code will work even on c++11, by replacing `std::rbegin` with `.rbegin()`.